# ctrl+z does not do anything

Tags: sms, at-command, hyperterminal

i am using AT commands to test sending sms messages from pc to mobile.  i have been referring to the following links:

http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/
http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp

when i press ctrl+z, nothing happens. No matter how long i wait, it just shows a blinking cursor like this. Ideally after a few seconds, it must display `+CMGS: 62` if sms is send properly.

could anyone point out what might be wrong?

[image]

Comment: What do you get when you enter at+cscs?

Comment: @SList I get AT
OK
+CSCS: "PCCP437"

OK

Comment: Try changing it to "IRA" or "GSM" (assuming that AT+CSCS=? supports these values)?  You should see a little arrow for Ctrl-Z, by the way.

Comment: @SList   AT+CSCS="IRA" or AT+CSCS="GSM" gives me a CME ERROR:4 which means this operation is not allowed. It supports only PCCP437

Comment: @SList do u happen to know what does PCCP437 mean here?

Comment: It's a character coding scheme. If you do AT+CSCS=?, you should get a list of the types of character coding supported by your modem.  Mine supports IRA, GSM and UCS2, but I can only send SMSs by entering text like you do above with IRA and GSM.  Not sure why it doesn't work for UCS2.

Comment: also, please note: i have connected my phone to my computer to use as a gsm modem.and i am sending a message to my phone itself. till the time my phone was connected to my pc, nothing happened. but when i disconnected my phone, i received the message 'Hello!1".. so does that mean that it is because i am basically sending msg from my my phone to my phone, it does not accept ctrl+z??

Comment: Here's the standard definition of AT commands from 3GPP (the standards body for UMTS): http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm

Comment: @SList Ohh thanks for that. my phone only supports PCCP437. thats what it shows.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference that it was to your own phone, but you can easily test that by sending to someone else's phone.  I guess you didn't see the message while your phone was connected, because it wasn't in phone mode?

Comment: @SList  the message goes out only on disconnecting my phone. and thats why i dont get the confirmation +cmgs: 62 on pressing ctrl+z

Comment: OK, so it seems that your phone is not very good at being a modem :-)